# VS2017 Community no references

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Just installed Visual Studio 2017 Community with the following workloads:
1) .NET Core cross-platform development
2) ASP.NET and web development
3) Azure development
4) Data storage and processing

I launched VS and created a new test project.  When it created a default Class1 class, I immediate get the error: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported.  Looking at my references I don't see any list of any kind (unlike previous versions of VS).  Am I suppose to download/install some default libs or something for VS to make this work? 
[image][image]

Comment: It is entirely normal, the programmers that work on .NETCore have machines that are at least an order of magnitude faster than mere mortals like you and me use.  Tap your foot at least twenty times before you ask for help.  Also gives you enough time to ponder if you *really* meant to create a .NETCore project.  Give it another year or two so they can actually get it done.

Comment: @Hans Huh?  LOL!

Comment: Can reproduce similar error on Mac with VSCode and `dotnet new console`. But this only affect the editing experience, and the project compiles/runs fine.

Comment: @Lex ok so is this a bug with VS2017 community or do I need to do something extra to get this to work?  I have some new developers learning VS and they can't get past this stage.

Comment: Have you tried running dotnet restore from the command prompt?

Comment: @Robert Nope that didn't work.  Same issue described here:  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/17291/systemobject-is-not-defined-in-net-standard-class.html